# Improve upon: $\sqrt[4]{3^4+2^4+\frac{1}{2+(\frac{2}{3})^2}} \approx \pi$

Tags: pi

So here we have an approximate value of $\pi$.
$$\sqrt[4]{3^4+2^4+\frac{1}{2+(\frac{2}{3})^2}} \approx \pi$$

$$3.14159265262 \ldots \approx 3.14159265358\ldots$$

How could one get a better approximation?

Highly appreciated,

Cro-Magnon

Comment: By improve approximation, do you mean to simplify the expression or to find a better approximation?

Comment: $$\sqrt[4]{3^4+2^4+\frac{1}{2+(\frac{2}{3})^2}} + .0000000001$$

Comment: @Sil a better approximation, sorry.

Comment: @UMbertoP. Is there a way to improve upon it inside the square root?

Comment: In that case there are many formulas (usually infinite sums) in which you can evaluate more terms to get better precision: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Comment: @Sil Great, I will pursue that. So fun to try and get closer and closer to the value of $\pi$. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, but keep in mind that $\pi$ is transcendental number, which makes this a bit less interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\pi^4$ happens to have a very good rational approximation
$$ \pi^4 \approx 97 + \dfrac{1}{2 + \dfrac{1}{2 + \dfrac{1}{4}}} = \dfrac{2143}{22}$$
with error approximately $1.25 \times 10^{-7}$, 
which comes from the fact that the continued fraction
$$ \pi^4 = [97;2,2,3,1,16539,1,6,7,\ldots]$$
has a large element $16539$.  You're writing $97 = 3^4 + 2^4$
and $ 2 + 1/4 = (3/2)^2$.

Another example is

$$ (\pi + 7)^{4/9} = [2,1,4,23571, \ldots]$$
so that
$$ \pi \approx \left(3 - \dfrac{1}{5}\right)^{9/4} - 7 $$
with error approximately $1.4 \times 10^{-5}$.
And another:
$$ \pi \approx 801^{1/5} - \dfrac{2}{3}$$
with error approximately $9.1 \times 10^{-8}$.

Comment: Even better, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"Improve upon" is vague.  Here is one way to improve upon the OP.  The expression given yields 9 digits of accuracy, and uses eighteen symbols (surd, two fractions, three plusses, two parentheses, and ten digits).

Meanwhile, the more mundane expression $$\frac{312689}{99532}$$ achieves 11 digits of accuracy using only twelve symbols.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have the following interesting formula
$$\pi \approx\frac{\ln(640320^3+744)}{\sqrt{163}}$$ which gives $30$ "digits of accuracy".

(Thanks for the English expression in quotes to @vadim123. The best rational approximation I knew was $\pi \approx  \frac{22}{17}+\frac{37}{47}+\frac{88}{83}$ which gives $9$ exacts digits).

Comment: You are welcome. The first time I saw it that way impresses me a lot.